# Can we apply database encryption in mongodb community edition?

Tags: mongodb, encryption

I know there's features in mongodb Entreprise edition that allow encryption. I'm using mongodb community edition for personal project and i want to keep my database safe and encrypted.
Is there any way to encrypt my database within this community edition? Thank you

Comment: Two suggestions - download the trial edition of the enterprise version or roll your own?  p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: @Vérace thank you :) actually i had to enable the ecryption and decryption by my own in nodejs side